# Converting MySQL results to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

HI i have a peice of code which takes information from a xml file using the below peice of code:

```
if (file_exists('locations.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('locations.xml');
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    print_r($json);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open locations.xml.');
}
```

Below is the layout of the xml page

```
   <locations>
     <location>
       <id>12196</title>
       <uid>010203</uid>
       <lat>34.134103</lat>
       <lng>-118.321694</lng>
      </location>
    <location>
```

This works fine, now what i want to do is replace the code above to take information straight from the database.  and have the following peice of Code:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM track ORDER BY id");
  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
  }
  print json_encode($rows);
```

When retrieving the information from the database it works well.  However i have noticed that when i retrieve the data the format is slightly different for example.

using the first method places location in front of the results, like this.

```
  {"location":[{"id":"12196"
```

and the second method just returns this,

```
  [{"id":"12196","uid":"010203"
```

I have tried severals ways to get the second format to include the location, but can not seem to get it to work.  and i think the rest of my code uses the location tag to assign the information.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows['location'][] = $row;
  }
  print json_encode($rows);
```